# CSV/Text in DataGrid Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, csv, text, datagrid

I cannot seem to figure out how to add my CSV File in a DataGrid.
Can someone explain me what my approach should be?

Lets say i have a CSV file with the following content in my csv file:

```
ID;Name;Age;Gender
01;Jason;23;Male
02;Lela;29;Female
```

Really need some help here

Comment: CSV - Comma Separated...

Comment: Its not required to use comma's, semicolons will do also

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Forget `DataTable`-based stuff. It's horrendous. It is not strongly typed and it forces you to all sorts of "magic-string" based hacks.

Instead, create a proper strongly-typed Data Model:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
}

public enum Gender
{
    Male,
    Female
}
```

Then create a Service that can load Data from the File:

```
public static class PersonService
{
    public static List<Person> ReadFile(string filepath)
    {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath);

        var data = from l in lines.Skip(1)
                   let split = l.Split(';')
                   select new Person
                   {
                       Id = int.Parse(split[0]),
                       Name = split[1],
                       Age = int.Parse(split[2]),
                       Gender = (Gender)Enum.Parse(typeof(Gender), split[3])
                   };

        return data.ToList();
    }
}
```

And then use that to populate the UI:

```
public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    public Window2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = PersonService.ReadFile(@"c:\file.csv");
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication14.Window2"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window2" Height="300" Width="300">
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
</Window>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: i am getting errors but no errors are being displayed in the "Error list". I did a clean (under build)

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Although i found some other way: kept it simple

This is my way i just figured:

```
//Location of CSV File
        string CSVDataBase = @"C:\CSVDatabase.csv";

        //Create Collection for DataGrid Source
        ICollection CreateDataSource()
        {
            //Create new DataTables and Rows
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataRow dr;

            //Create Column Headers
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Age", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Gender", typeof(string)));


            //For each line in the File
            foreach (string Line in File.ReadLines(CSVDataBase))
            {
                //Split lines at delimiter ';''

                //Create new Row
                dr = dt.NewRow();

                //ID=
                dr[0] = Line.Split(';').ElementAt(0);

                //Name =
                dr[1] = Line.Split(';').ElementAt(1);

                //Age=
                dr[2] = Line.Split(';').ElementAt(2);

                //Gender= 
                dr[3] = Line.Split(';').ElementAt(3);

                //Add the row we created
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

            //Return Dataview 
            DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
            return dv;
        }
```

Then all i had to do is:

```
public void loadDataGridView()
{
  //Load everything in datagrid
  myDataGrid.ItemsSource = CreateDataSource();
}
```

Thats it! is this a good approach?
Anyway Thanks for the help.