# Why is every single cell in my Data Grid showing "System.Data.DataRowView" instead of actual data? (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I'm trying to read a csv into my data grid. All I need to do is get the csv and put it in a data grid. This is the C# that I have (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574464/csv-text-in-datagrid-wpf)):

```
            public ICollection CreateDataSource()
            {
                string CSVDataBase = @"C:\Users\Laura\source\repos\Inveni\Inveni\inventory.csv";
                //Create new DataTables and Rows
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                DataRow dr;

                //Create Column Headers
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(int)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Type", typeof(string)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Brand", typeof(string)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Line", typeof(string)));

                //For each line in the File
                foreach (string Line in File.ReadLines(CSVDataBase))
                {
                    //Split lines at delimiter ';''

                    //Create new Row
                    dr = dt.NewRow();

                    //ID=
                    dr[0] = Line.Split(',').ElementAt(0);

                    //Type =
                    dr[1] = Line.Split(',').ElementAt(1);

                    //Brand=
                    dr[2] = Line.Split(',').ElementAt(2);

                    //Line= 
                    dr[3] = Line.Split(',').ElementAt(3);

                    //Add the row we created
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
                //Return Dataview 
                DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
                return dv;
            }
```

And then:

```
dgvInventory.ItemsSource = CreateDataSource();
```

And in my XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgvInventory" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="#FF0B123F" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}" Header="ID"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}" Header="Type"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}" Header="Brand"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}" Header="Line"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

The output from this is every single cell showing "System.Data.DataRowView" instead of actual data.
[System.Data.DataRowView Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPmKB.png)

How can I make my data grid show correct data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column bindings must use the respective property paths:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ID}" Header="ID"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Type}" Header="Type"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Brand}" Header="Brand"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Line}" Header="Line"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

or simpler, you don't explicitly declare the Columns at all and don't set `AutoGenerateColumns="False"`.

Also note that `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` is pointless when you assign the ItemsSource property in code behind.

---

And you don't need much more than the following to create the source collection:

```
private IEnumerable CreateDataSource()
{
    var CSVDataBase = ...

    return File.ReadLines(CSVDataBase).Select(
        line =>
        {
            var items = line.Split(',');
            return new
            {
                ID = int.Parse(items[0]),
                Type = items[1],
                Brand = items[2],
                Line = items[3]
            };
        });
}
```