# Revit API for Type catalog popup

Tags: revit-api

When I am using the Load Family command manually, then the Type Catalog Popup is coming as like below image.

[image: click here]

But by the Revit api programming the popup is not coming while using the `Loadfamily()` api function. Even though the required .TXT file is available on the same working directory.

Could you please help us to overcome this?

Advance thanks for your support

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? Do you want that pop-up to show when you run your command? Or do you want to programmatically add all the types from the type catalog?

Comment: pop-up to show when run the command by revit API

Comment: I think the community guru egeer has shared the good suggestion: either calling built-in command (just like the end user clicking the menu of Load Family) or implementing the type catalog popout by yourself, asking the user to select  and call LoadFamily API.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible to programmatically launch the type catalog dialog separate from the built-in Load Family command. This leaves you with two choices:

1. Use the built-in common programmatically using `PostCommand`
   Note that you can only use one `PostCommand` call per `IExternalCommand` execution

```cs
    [Transaction(TransactionMode.Manual)]
    public class LoadFamilyWithTypeCatalog : IExternalCommand
    {
        public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, ElementSet elements)
        {
            var commandId = RevitCommandId.LookupCommandId("ID_FAMILY_LOAD");
            commandData.Application.PostCommand(commandId);

            return Result.Succeeded;
        }
    }
```

2. Roll your own type catalog selection UI. This shouldn’t be too difficult since the type catalog is just a csv. Once you have asked the user which rows to import, then you can create/delete the symbols by iterating over the selected rows. Here is a pretty crude example of how to do that:

#### Revit Command

```cs
    [Transaction(TransactionMode.Manual)]
    public class LoadFamilyWithTypeCatalog_CustomUI : IExternalCommand
    {
        public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, ElementSet elements)
        {
            var doc = commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument.Document;

            var path = @"C:\StackOverflow\Box.rfa";

            using (var t = new Transaction(doc, "Load Family"))
            {
                t.Start();

                var typeCatalogForm = new TypeCatalogForm();
                typeCatalogForm.ShowDialog();

                // Load Selected Symbols
                var selectedSymbolNames = typeCatalogForm.Types.Table.Rows
                    .OfType<DataRow>()
                    .Where(x => x[0] is bool selected && selected)
                    .Select(x => x["Type"] as string)
                    .ToHashSet();

                foreach (var type in selectedSymbolNames)
                {
                    doc.LoadFamilySymbol(path, type);
                }

                t.Commit();
            }

            return Result.Succeeded;
        }
    }
```

#### DataGrid/CSV Import:

Note that you would probably want to clean this up a bit, as this is just to illustrate how it could be done.
CSV import borrowed and modified from the answer by Nick Prozee here: [CSV/Text in DataGrid Wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574464/csv-text-in-datagrid-wpf)

```cs
    public partial class TypeCatalogForm: Window
    {
        public DataView Types { get; set; }

        public TypeCatalog()
        {
            Types = CreateDataSource();
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        string CSVDataBase = @"c:\StackOverflow\Box.txt";

        //Create Collection for DataGrid Source
        DataView CreateDataSource()
        {
            //Create new DataTables and Rows
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Selected", typeof(bool));
            DataRow dr;

            bool firstRow = true;
            var lines = File.ReadLines(CSVDataBase);
            //For each line in the File
            foreach (string Line in lines)
            {
                var cols = Line.Split(',');
                if (firstRow) // first row is the headers
                {
                    bool firstCol = true;
                    foreach (var col in cols)
                    {
                        if (firstCol)
                        {
                            firstCol = false;
                            dt.Columns.Add("Type"); // first column doesn't have a header in the text file
                            continue;
                        }

                        // the headers have a lot of extra stuff we don't care about
                        string cleanedHeader = col.Split('#')[0].Split('[')[0];
                        dt.Columns.Add(cleanedHeader);
                    }

                    firstRow = false;
                    continue;
                }


                //Create new Row
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                for (var i = 0; i < cols.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    dr[i+1] = cols[i];
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

            //Return Dataview 
            DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
            return dv;
        }
    }
```

#### xaml

```xml
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Types}" />
    </Grid>
```

#### Result

[image]